# Spring Batch Admin - Not showing JSON endpoints

Tags: json, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

On the [Spring Batch Admin JSON API Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/json.html) I read that:

> "Spring Batch Admin can act as a JSON web service. All the main HTML
>   UI features can be accessed by JSON clients. In general, the recipe
>   for doing this is to take a normal HTML URL from the UI application
>   and add a .json suffix. All the JSON endpoints are listed on the home
>   page of the sample application."

But in my Spring Batch Admin Console I don't see any JSON endpoints.

I also tried to call directly the normal endpoints adding the .json like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin/batch/jobs.json
```

But the result is always an HTML document.

Does anybody knows if there is a particular setting to enable for viewing JSON endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I auto answer :D the JSON endpoints were introduced since 1.2.0 version of Spring Batch Admin Console, while we are using version 1.0.0.